# Is it possible to have acces to innerHTML 'id' from otger part of the code?

Tags: javascript

I have following code, where, based on event, I add some html code. I would like to refer to 'id' from this dynamically injected html in other event (or just from other part of the code):

```
<div id="choice"></div>
```

```
var decisionList = document.getElementById("decisionList");

decisionList.addEventListener("change", function () {

var finalChoice = document.getElementById("choice");
finalChoice.innerHTML='<input id="finalDate" type="date">'  
         
 }
```

and other event referring to 'id' from innerHTML:

```
var payment = document.getElementById("finalDate");

payment.addEventListener("change", function () {

var textDate = payment.textContent; 
alert(textDate);

})
```

The above is not working. Is it possible or not?

Comment: is the input id="finalDate" appear in document ? Are you shure that code refering to this element is runing after adding "finalDate" to html ?

Comment: No, it's not appearing. Yes, first I need to add it, once it's added and then changed (date) then some other code is executed. I also thought about remaining input id='finalDate' in the main html code and hide it when not necessary but don't know which option is better

Comment: i think hiding is more performant. you don't change DOM, you change only style display or visibility. just add class date--hidden and toggle them. it will be much easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but make that payment getter lazy. What that means is, instead of setting up that *second* change listener right away (in your other code), make that other code a function. Then in your first trigger, where you created the extra div or input or something, call that setup function.

```
decisionList.addEventListener("change", function () {
  const finalChoice = document.getElementById("choice");
  finalChoice.innerHTML='<input id="finalDate" type="date">'  
  createFinalDateListener();
}

function createFinalDateListener() {
  const payment = document.getElementById("finalDate"); 
  payment.addEventListener("change", function () {
    const textDate = payment.textContent; 
    alert(textDate);
  });
}
```

---

Here's a similar example. I do not have the input immediately. Or listener. And I only create a listener after I create the input.

```js
// Here's the main trigger
function addExtraElements() {
  // let's create a datepicker dynamically.
  document.querySelector('#placeholder').innerHTML = '<input type="date" placeholder="pick date">';
  listenDateChanges();
  // TODO: don't forget to add cleanup code! Each time you fill that innerHTML, the old listener will remain
}

// Here's your datepicker listener
function listenDateChanges() {
  const datePickerEl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
  if (!datePickerEl) {
    console.log('no picker');
    return;
  }
  datePickerEl.addEventListener('change', () => alert(datePickerEl.value));
}
```

```html
<div id="placeholder">
  Placeholder
</div>
<button onclick="addExtraElements()">Add extra elements</button>
```

Comment: ok thanks but my question is: what's the difference in declaring finalChoice as const instead of var?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's just a habbit. Since ~ca 2015 it was part of standard JavaScript and I have been using it like that - only Internet Explorer didn't support it (and that thing isn't even made any more).

As for the actual difference, two things: one, you can't modify the value once you assign it (use `let` for that) and two, **scope**. If you use a `var`, then in theory you can access that `var` even before you assigned it, accidentally. And by using const, your code will fail, and your editor will (hopefully) tell you that e.g. `finalChoice` is not available where you wanted it.

Comment: Basically my example would work even with `var` instead of const - it's just a good habbit to use modern standards instead.

Comment: ok, many thanks! I only changed ```const textDate = payment.textContent; ``` for ```const textDate = payment.value;``` and it works smoothly

Comment: Glad I could help, that's what SO is about.

Comment: one more question - assuming I have some variables/constants in main trigger and I'm passing them to second addEventListener - do I need to find corresponding cells (in a row) again? I don't know how to do this. Suppose I applied those listeners to 100 rows

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Maybe you can ask another SO question with the details of what your problem is. But think of it like this. With most of JavaScript, you're not creating _code to run directly_. You're creating functions that someone will call sometimes later. When they do, they can pass them arguments, give hints etc. You can even create a function returning another function. It is not imperative at all - most code is not running when you start the app - it's running sometimes later in some unexpected place. I don't know if I made my point accross. Ask more if not.

Comment: I solved my problem:) it works as I wanted. But many thanks for your explanations:)